# VS2015 IDE Intellisense bug when reference core lib from a .net 4.6. console application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

In a test project I created a core project with a test class .

I configured the project in the project.json to compile as core and dnx like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    },
    "dnx46": {
      "imports": "dnx46"
    } 

  }
}
```

now i create a .net 4.6.2 console project and add manually reference to the output form this folder `bin\Debug\dnx46`

now when i instantiate the class and call a method on it it works. It gets compiled and the runtime returns the currect result.

But the IDE seems to not resolve the types for intellisense

am I doing something wrong?[image]

What am I missing?

This can also be found at this issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/875

Comment: Probably it's the same as in here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40709226/5311735

Comment: no it isn't in my case the project is compiled successfully and is running.

Comment: In that case it is too, if you read the answer (OP was thinking that it's not, but it is - just like in your case).

Comment: All in all, you can try to browse .net core tooling issues: https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues. There are many of them related to intellisense, maybe you will find your concrete situation there. That situation is clearly a bug, and it's not an uncommon one.

Comment: I don't believe this as I don't reference the projecti na solution., I reference the assembly from the output, so there aren't multiple projects in it

Comment: Yes you are right, that's a bit different bug, missed that you reference directly.

Comment: i'll open a ticket there maybe the issues are at least linked.

Comment: Compared to VSCode which updates more often to catch up with the changes, I believe VS might give you more issues than you imagine. Except reporting to Microsoft and hope they can fix, I don't think posting on SO can lead to any solution. It is simply a Roslyn related bug on .NET Core support.